# How to catch this exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception

If the user enters incorrect directory name which doesn't exists rsync generates this error. I am using `subprocess.Popen` with Python. How do I catch this error in Python?

```
rsync: link_stat "/fdsfsd" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1637) [Receiver=3.1.0dev]
    rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

Comment: What code throws this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't look like an exception but an error printed by `rsync`.  As such you can't catch it in Python.  What you can do is monitor the return code of the `Popen` object to see whether the process terminated successfully.  Read the documentation on [returncode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode).

If you want to try to parse the error message I suppose you could try that with regular expressions, but it's probably not worth it.  When you call an external process there is no general-purpose way to know how its printed error messages map onto Python exception types.  The program could do anything and fail in any unknown way.  Your best bet is simply to look at the returncode and, if it is nonzero then raise an exception saying "the external process failed somehow".  This is basically what `subprocess.check_call` does for you.

Comment: How can I do that? Using Regular Expression?

Comment: @user1881957: No, using the return code.  See my edited answer.